# Как изменить код скрипта, чтобы можно было его задавать нескольким элементам

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть такой код html:

```
        <div id="clockdiv" class='clockdiv'>
            <div>
                <span class="days"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">дня</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="hours"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">часа</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="minutes"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">минут</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="seconds"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">секунд</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

И такой JS скрипт:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = 'December 31 2016 23:59:59 GMT+02:00';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Подскажите, как нужно изменить код, чтобы я мог его применить еще к одному таймеру на странице с такой же датой отсчета (если не сложно, то еще интересно как можно изменить чтобы под разные даты) ?

Comment: вы же спрашивали уже. и я вам даже ссылку давал https://jsfiddle.net/r1tmrya7/ где работают два ваших таймера

Comment: Сори! Все работает! Огонь! Спасибо большое, видимо не увидел ответа... 
Могли бы Вы подсказать, что изменил, чтобы я обратил на это внимание в дальнейшем (когда сам смогу разбираться в JS ) ?

Comment: вообще ничего не менял - два id и две инициализации с разными id и разными датами - там, внизу  скрипта

Comment: Еще проблема, в Chrom'е все работает, а в Мозиле пишет NaN, как это можно исправить ?